# How to load/set TAGS from emacs startup?

Tags: emacs

I am relatively new to emacs and using emacs version 21.3.1 and trying out the ctags for emacs (mainly to jump to definitions).

I am working with a big solution with lots of projects. Problem is that whenever I am trying to jump to tags under a cursor using command M-. , it tries to find a tags table from current directory of the source file.

My TAGS file is located at the root of my solution. So I have to point to it using M-x visit-tags-table [path to my tag file].

Is there a way to set this when I start up emacs so I do not have to point to it every time?

Comment: Do you mean even after telling Emacs where the TAGS file is, it keeps asking for its location?

Comment: Once I specify it, it doesn't ask anymore. I just want this to be done on startup.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to set it in my .emacs file by adding
(setq tags-table-list '("[path to my tag file]"))

Comment: Are you using `emacsclient`? Do not open a new emacs for each file to be edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the variable `tags-file-name` is the one you want to set.

One way would be to set it in your `.emacs`, something like:

```
(setq tags-file-name "path/to/file")
```

I wouldn't do it, as it will fix the tags table globally, and in case you'd like to use a different table (say for a different project) this won't work.

It seems that you could use the so called *local variables* and set this one per file. Do `C-h v tags-file-name RET` to see some more info.

Comment: Your method worked too. However I have decided not to set the tags on start-up for the exact reason you mentioned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the recipe that ensures that you will always have an uptodate tag file loaded automagically whenever and wherever you start emacs.

1. Make an `emacs_startup.bash` file in your project directory
   that contains this:

   ```
   find . -name "*.yourCodeFileExtensionHere" -print | etags -
   cp TAGS ~/CurrentTagsCopy
   emacs
   ```
2. `chmod u+x emacs_startup.bash`
3. In your main emacs configuration file, add this line:

   ```
   (setq tags-file-name "~/CurrentTagsCopy")
   ```
4. To start work, cd to your project directory and do `./emacs_startup.bash`.

Comment: It sounds like this will create a quite long startup time for emacs.